# On click on SVG icon redirection to another page

Tags: reactjs, svg

How can I add href to SVG icon to redirect to another page after click on some icon? I save SVG icon as React Component, but I don't know what I need to do now to do this.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../style/icon-panel.css';
import { ReactComponent as Login } from '../icons/login.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Register } from '../icons/register.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Tender } from '../icons/tender.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Cash } from '../icons/cash.svg';

function IconPanel() {
  return (
    <div id="icon-panel-id" className="icon-panel">
      <Login />
      <Register />
      <Tender />
      <Cash />
    </div>
  );
}

export default IconPanel;
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding an `onClick` event? Or wrapping it in an `<a>` element? (Or `<Link>` if you're using react-router)

Comment: I do this in reverse sequence, <a> tag I place in ReactComponent. I didn't thing about that to do it in that sequence you say. Thank you for your answer, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this:

1. Add onClick event for the ReactComponent. Eg:

   `<Login onClick={() => history.push('/login')} />`
2. Wrap the svg in a `<div>` or `<a>`

   ```
    <div onClick={() => history.push('/login')}>
      <Login />
    </div>
   ```
3. Render the svg as image

   `<Image src={require('svg_path_here')} onClick={() => history.push('/login')} />`